# Where can I find the 2014 release of Medicare data from 2012?

Tags: data-request, government

I have read many news stories this week about a release of 2012 Medicare data (physician billing) that just happened.  Some news sites like NYTimes and the Washington Post have data browser tools on their site.

But where do I actually find the data itself?  I couldn't find any links to it from the articles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like this might be the data:
http://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/Medicare-Provider-Charge-Data/Physician-and-Other-Supplier.html

Comment: great data & resource! please click the 'answer' check mark if this link answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

An interactive browser interface to the dataset is also available at:

https://data.cms.gov/Medicare/Medicare-Provider-Utilization-and-Payment-Data-Phy/jzd2-pt4g